# When checkbox selected select dropdown should appear not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Basically, I have a checkbox.
If the checkbox is selected, the drop-down should appear. if unselected the drop down should not show up. Unfortunately, it's not working. This is my code below. It's not the full code but it's enough to see what's wrong.

```
<script>
$('[name="Lab Elective"]').on('change', function() {
  $('#Lab Elective g').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="Lab Elective" id="Lab Elective" value="some value">

<select id="Lab Elective g" name="Lab Elective g">
<option value="some value">some value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just remove spaces from id, and this should work:https://jsfiddle.net/un38znkd/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Avoid the use of jQuery.toggle, and be careful with the ID.

IDs containing spaces are trickier to select with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name="Lab Elective"]').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("[id='Lab Elective g']").show();
    } else {
      $("[id='Lab Elective g']").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="Lab Elective" id="Lab Elective" value="some value" checked>

<select id="Lab Elective g" name="Lab Elective g">
    <option value="some value">some value</option>
</select>
```

For this to default to unchecked and hidden, make the following adjustments:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Lab Elective" id="Lab Elective" value="some value">

<select id="Lab Elective g" name="Lab Elective g" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: its still not working. Does this script have to be placed somewhere specific ?

Comment: @James, it shouldn't, as long as you have jQuery properly loaded. I'll add a snippet.

Comment: yes please ill wait for the snippet to see why its not working for me

Comment: @James, here you go. (working on Win10: FF and Chrome) If there's a problem with this jQuery in your project, you may want to check the version, and watch the console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

IDs can't have spaces in them. Change the spaces in your IDs to something else such as `-`.

https://jsbin.com/famaqovumo/edit?html,css,js,console,output

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Lab Elective" id="Lab Elective" value="some value">

<select id="Lab-Elective-g" name="Lab Elective g">
<option value="some value">some value</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
     display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$('[name="Lab Elective"]').on('change', function() {
  $('#Lab-Elective-g').toggleClass('hidden',!$(this).is(':checked'));
}).change();
```

Comment: i don't want to remove the spaces since my code is setup with these spaces. Id have to do a lot of changes. Any other way to make it work?

Comment: @James https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html spaces are not valid in IDs based on the HTML spec. You will probably run into other problems if you aren't writing valid HTML. I suggest you cut your losses and make the change now. For that reason, I'm not going to provide a workaround.

Comment: Definitely worth considering refactoring your code to be standards compliant, _without spaces in IDs_.

Comment: @bassxzero, did you just downvote me out of spite!? Wow.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas you could call it that. Honestly I don't care that much, but showing him a workaround is probably going to cause more questions in the future. Also, using `hide` and `show` is magic and i don't recommend using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function show_hide_sel()
{
   if( $('input[name="Lab Elective"]').is(':checked') )
   {
     $('#Lab_Elective_g').show();
   }
   else
   {
     $('#Lab_Elective_g').hide();
   }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[name="Lab Elective"]').on('click', function() {
    show_hide_sel();
  });

  show_hide_sel();
});
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="Lab Elective" id="Lab Elective" value="some value">

<select id="Lab_Elective_g" name="Lab Elective g">
<option value="some value">some value</option>
```

Comment: then change reference to $('[id="Lab Elective g"]') , but this is slower way to refer . bad practice .

Comment: FYI , HTML 4.1 standard not allow space in the ID. HTML5 allow.